# Does Google App Engine have a default "under construction" page?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

In the dashboard of GAE (https://appengine.google.com), I cannot find a default "under construction" page. I can also create a page and deploy it to GAE. But it is very time consuming if every time I have to do it when I want to manage the site. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

Answer [1]
Why don't you just run a version until another is ready and then switch.  Sorry I don't understand the need.  If version 1 is running, why can't it run until you have version 2 tested and deployed and ready to run?

Answer [2] Just have one version that serves only the "under construction" page.  Switch to and away from it as needed.

It's really easy to select the running version.  Just select "versions" in the  dashboard and you can see the option.